# jQuery, ajax Is that possible set script as dataType?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This code working on OSX but not working on Win7, giving '500 internal server error'.
i set dataType to javascript, text, xml etc. but my problem wasn't solved, couldn't get response.
i have to work on windows because my webservice will fetch data from mssql.

```
$.ajax(
  {
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "script",
    url: "http://localhost:49292/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld",
    success: function() { console.log('successful access!!!'); },
    error: function() { console.log('error!!!!'); }
  });
```

Comment: Yes you should be able to use either `xml, json, script, or html` as `dataType`. What error do you get? Have your tried using something like `firebug` to see what happens with the request? If you remove the `dataType` does it work then? Otherwise I'm thinking perhaps it's something else that is wrong with your ajax call ie the `url`? Also, try switching request method from `POST` to `GET`.

Comment: i tried to remove so status changed to '200 OK' but no response.

Comment: i can't understand that how it works on OSX but doesn't work on Win7?

Comment: Have you tried changing `POST` to `GET`? If I understand it correctly `script` will be evaluated as javascript and return the response in plain text, so I guess you could try to use `dataType: text` instead.

Comment: What is the result if you access the url irectly from your browser ?

Comment: When i changed to GET firebug status turned '500 internal server error'.

Comment: if i access it directly from my browser result is true like that.
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello World</string>`